# Вывод названий таблиц с помощью PHP

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

Имеется БД с неизвестным количеством таблиц.

Как можно получить и вывести названия таблиц через PHP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для MySQL можно вывести результаты данного запроса:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE() 
  AND TABLE_NAME LIKE 'префикс-названия-таблиц%'
```

P.S. Часть условия `AND TABLE_NAME LIKE 'префикс-названия-таблиц%'` нужна, если в одной базе храните таблицы от разных приложений. Если этого нет, то данную часть условия можно убрать из запроса.

Answer (score 2):

Еще можно посмотреть список всех таблиц текущей БД

```
SHOW TABLES
```

Дока https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-tables.html