# Проверка базы данных на наличие в ней таблиц. MySql + PHP

Tags: mysql

Какой запрос отправить в базу данных чтобы получить список таблиц?

Comment: http://localhost/phpmyadmin/

Comment: `show  tables ;`

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/780325/256824

Answer (score 3):

Вам достаточно выполнить запрос `SHOW TABLES`:

```sql
SHOW TABLES FROM `database`;
# Где "database" — название вашей базы данных
```

[Подробная информация в документации MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-tables.html)